# unrecognized selector sent to instance resignFirstResponder

Tags: ios, objective-c, resignfirstresponder, tpkeyboardavoiding

I'm using [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) in my app to hide move text fields when the keyboard is showing, but I'm getting an exception when I try to end editing the text field. It's coming from this method in TPKeyboardAvoiding:

```
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView* view =[self TPKeyboardAvoiding_findFirstResponderBeneathView:self];
    NSLog(@"%@",[view description]);
    [view resignFirstResponder]; //this line gives the exception
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

I'm a bit confused here. Shouldn't all UIViews respond to `resignFirstResponder`? Thanks for the help.

Full error:

```
2014-03-25 17:40:39.919 Rysk[5553:70b] -[MenuViewController textFieldDidBeginEditing:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb63c820
```

Comment: Try this instead: `[self.view endEditing:YES];`

Comment: Try `if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] || [view isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {[view resignFirstResponder]; }`

Comment: @troop231 I'm getting an exception on that too

Comment: How about `[view endEditing:YES];`

Comment: I got an exception on that as well

Comment: resignFirstResponder can be called on objects which are subclasses of UIResponder (UIView for example). you better check if you're calling this on appropriate object. do a NSLog and print the object view to see.

Comment: @nsuinteger, your guess is correct to NSLog the object but if you will go with the TPKeyboardAvoid class you will see it check for UITextField and UITextView's only. I think it will not give go ahead. but lets see.

Comment: if you want to simply avoid the exception then use this, put an else block & print the object so you will know when it wont work but will not give exception 

`if ([view respondsToSelector:@selector(resignFirstResponder)] ) { [view resignFirstResponder]; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by having my view controller than contains the TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView implement the UITextFieldDelegate protocol. Most importantly, these two methods:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have called `[yourTextField resignFirstResponder]` **as well**. So it is possible that the UITextField (in the code you have provided) **is not the FirstResponder at that point**. I would suggest to adjust your code like this:

```
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView* view =[self TPKeyboardAvoiding_findFirstResponderBeneathView:self];

    if([view conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextFieldDelegate)] || [view conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextViewDelegate)]) && 
       [view isFirstResponder] && [view canResignFirstResponder])
    {
       [view resignFirstResponder];  
    }

    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Also, if you using PODs please make sure you are using a latest version, because the one i am using has something like this in this event:

```
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [[self TPKeyboardAvoiding_findFirstResponderBeneathView:self] resignFirstResponder];
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still getting an unrecognized selector error on that line though. My code used to be like that as well, I've changed it a bit trying to find where the error was.

Comment: Do you resign by yourself too ? I mean outside this class ? check my updates as well

Comment: I still get the same exception checking if it can resignFirstResponder. The only places resignFirstResponder is called is inside that class

Comment: Do you get this exception on a single screen or at application level ? Can you post the complete error messsage? I guess it also tells which selector is unrecognized and in which controller.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as follows:

```
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView* view =[self TPKeyboardAvoiding_findFirstResponderBeneathView:self];
    NSLog(@"%@",[view description]);
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField *myTextField = (UITextField *)view;
        [myTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still getting an exception on the resignFirstResponder line

Comment: Whats the exception saying?

Comment: 'unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb44b1a0'

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple method....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //--Gesture to resign keyborad on touch outside
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}


//-- Resign keyboard on touch UIView
-(void)dismissKeyboard
{
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: First 3 lines in viewDidLoad of your .m file.. next method dismissKeyboard place anywhere of the code...

Comment: it's giving me an error with finding self.fields_view. I assume I should replace that with a text field, but I have multiple text fields